# Save image from iOS WebApp to Photo Library

Tags: html, ios, web-applications, hyperlink, download

Ok so I've got an image that I want users to be able to click a link like the one below and it offers to save, rather than just getting users to click and hold the image. Cant find any documentation about this online, most people are trying to disable the click and hold feature, when I just want a link that does it quicker.

Is there anyway? Heres all i can think of the try but cant get to work.

```
<a href="himage_link.jpg" download>Save Image to Library</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Safari and other IOS browsers only access the filesystem with user input. So, pressing and holding is the only way to save it to the camera roll. It has something to do with sandboxing. Check here: [Sandbox_Wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security))